# ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 upgrade disk filter writes not supported

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

When I upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 or do a clean installation I get:
`Error: diskfilter writes not suported`.

I have looked around on previous posts and the suggested solutions have not worked for me.  I have a working version of 12.04 with zimbra on it so I don't want to go forward with upgrading unless I'm certain I have a working solution.

I have tried many things including replacing `etc/grub.d/10_linux` with `quick_boot="1"` with `quick_boot="0"` etc.

Another question would also be what is a diskfilter?

I am eager to look at having 14.04 up and running as 12.04 will be going out of support at some stage.  I'm going to kick up a  virtual box to see if I can replicate the issue in some way.

Comment: Please, read this link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/468466/why-this-occurs-error-diskfilter-writes-are-not-supported
It works for me

Comment: @Andy: Did you try [the other suggested solution](/a/498281) to the question Boyan refers to?