# How do I resolve the "Diskfilter writes are not supported" error?

Tags: 14.04, boot

After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS, I began to see an error during startup:

```
error: Diskfilter writes are not supported.
press any key to continue...
```

I tried applying the patch suggested at https://askubuntu.com/a/498281/154956 but ended up with an unusable system (I may have done it incorrectly).

I have my BIOS set to ENHANCED SATA mode.

Answer (score 1):

Switching my BIOS to AHCI solved the problem.