# grub2: Booting operating system booted last time, the "saved method", throws "error: Diskfilter writes are not supported". How to resolve?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, lvm

I have found [excellent solution to dual boot configuration selection of default OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader) to be last saved OS (great for update restarts). Editing and update of grub file went without any problems, but after reboot, right after unchanged grub menu selection

```
error: Diskfilter writes are not supported
```

is reported and OS selected in grub menu (or default OS) is booted (not the last saved).

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as default on /dev/sda1 in Linux LVM (Bootable) partition and Windows 10 on separate disk /dev/sdb1 with NTFS/exFAT/HPFS (Bootable) partition. How to make it work as descibed in original post?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't make it clear as to which GRUB file you edited, and what changes that you made. Revert whatever edits you made.

You **never** should edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

You **do** want to edit `/etc/default/grub`. Making the following changes...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved    <- edit this existing line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true <- add this line
```

This will allow GRUB to remember the last OS that you booted, until such time you select a different OS to boot.

`sudo update-grub` # write changes to disk

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Update #1:**

This won't work on LVM.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468466/diskfilter-writes-are-not-supported-what-triggers-this-error/498281#498281) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1274320) for more info about this.

Comment: I did exactly the changes you are suggesting with command: `sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub` 
It might be problem related to LVM partition (I do not have RAID) as in this [8 years old bug report.](https://askubuntu.com/a/498281/852151)

Comment: @JosefŠvenda Is /etc/default/grub the only file that you edited?

Comment: @JosefŠvenda You may have to revert your GRUB_DEFAULT and GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT parameters.

Comment: Yes, I've edited only /etc/default/grub and went back to old value at GRUB_DEFAULT and commented out GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT. Error then disappeared, but "saved method" booting is not working.