# My ubuntu 20.04 server boots but freezes on the grub error message disk filter writes are not supported

Tags: server, grub2, 20.04, raid

My ubuntu 20.04 server boots but freezes on the grub error message disk filter writes are not supported.
I can't find a way to make it leave the page so I can run GRUB commands. the only way I've been able to access it was through the ubuntu server installation media I was able to mount the drive but sudo grub-install was not a recognized command there. right now This uses a software raid and I'd like to try and keep it intact.

Comment: [This answer here might help](https://askubuntu.com/a/498281/1091774). Boot the machine with the installation media and perform the fix from there 